# Determine if new deployment (database exists)

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I'm using SSDT for database deployments.  I've got static data being added from a post-deployment script.  There's a lot of data though and I don't want it done if not necessary.

basically what I need is:

```
if($newdeployment)
:r .\scripts\insertstaticdata.sql
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What would you want to have happen if one row of the static data got deleted by accident? Or modified incorrectly?

Comment: These are dev/test environments so it doesn't matter - the data set is simply to big to deploy all the data everytime someone commits a schema change

Comment: I would just suggest (more for future readers than for you), that such a decision be made based on the amount of time and resources it takes to deploy all the data all of the time, as opposed to the size of the script  necessary to do the deployment. Also, consider a BULK INSERT to a staging table, followed by a MERGE from the staging table to the live table.

Comment: I appreciate your input but I don't want to deploy my static data every time, I want to determine if the database is being created from scratch or not and deploy data depending on that

Comment: `if not exists(SELECT * FROM SomeTableWithStaticData)...` ?

Comment: What if during population of static data a problem occurs, deployment script won't drop the database, unless you have that piece code seperately?
I think your statement is good enough, let the control of $newdeployment be with the used and passed a parameter during deployment.

IF(($newdeployment) = 1)
BEGIN
    :r .\scripts\insertstaticdata.sql
END

Answer (score 0):

We did this by setting up a specific publish profile for "New" that would re-create the DB and if that variable was set, it would run the "insert new data" script. Otherwise for all other types of releases, it would just run the normal post-deploy scripts. Add a couple of Begin/End wrappers around your IF/ELSE to catch all scripts at once and you should be good.

Otherwise, you could consider looking in a table that definitely should have data and do an IF NOT EXISTS (select * from MyTable) check against it to see if you should run the populate all data script.